# How to get Cell ID and LAC without GPS?

Tags: android

Working lower but not in android Pie(9) devices

```
location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();

String lac = String.valueOf(location.getLac());
String cid = String.valueOf(location.getCid());
```